# Unit tests fail only in ARM

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, raspberry-pi

I am working on a multithreaded program for a Raspberry Pi, and I have noticed that our current code runs perfectly in my computer and in the computers of other colleges, but it fails when running on ARM.

We are using C++11 for our project, and this is the output in our computer:

> ............
>   Success!
>   Test run complete. 12 tests run. 12 succeeded.

But when we try to run it on ARM, as you can see here: https://travis-ci.org/OpenStratos/server/builds/49297710

It says the following:

> ....
>   No output has been received in the last 10 minutes, this potentially indicates a stalled build or something wrong with the build itself.

After some debugging, I have understood that the issue comes to this code: https://github.com/OpenStratos/server/blob/feature/temperature/serial/Serial.cpp#L91

```
this->open = false;
while( ! this->stopped);
```

And there is another thread doing the opposite:

```
while(this->open)
{
    // Do stuff
}
this->stopped = true;
```

The first code is called when I need to stop the thread, and the double flag is ussed for the thread to be able to update the current object even if it's stopping. Both variables are of type std::atomic_bool, but it seems that in the `while ( ! this->stopped);` it does not check for it, ant it supposes a `while (true);`.

Is this the case? how can it be solved? why does it work differently on my x86_64 processor than on the ARM?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Which compiler? Which command line options?

Comment: Compiler and stdlib versions on systems ? Also, can you try using the load/store methods which let you pass ordering details.

Comment: Why don't you use normal threads synchronization mechanisms? `while( ! this->stopped);` is bad way to do it.

Comment: I'm using **g++** with the command line options **-std=c++** and **-Wno-unused-result**. The compiler version is **4.9.1**. I do not understand what do you mean with _normal threads synchronization_.

Comment: Try sticking a `-pthread` (or equivalent) option in there, as [the manual instructs you to do](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/using_concurrency.html).

Comment: As far as I know, using C++11 threads there is no need for -pthread.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally the issue was that the environment I was creating in Travis.ci was not working properly. In real ARM hardware works properly.

Answer (score 1):

The core guarantee made by `std::atomic<T>` is that you can always read *a* value. Consistency is not necessarily guaranteed.

Now, in this case you're relying on `.operator bool` which is equivalent to `.load(memory_order_seq_cst)` and `operator=(x)` which is `.store(x, memory_order_seq_cst)`. This should give you a sequential consistent memory order.

The order you're observing on ARM appears sequentially consistent to me. The fast that you're not *yet* seeing `stopped == true` is OK. There's no time limit on that. The compiler cannot swap the memory operation with another memory operation, but it may indefinitely delay it.

The main question is why this thread should be stopped at all. If there was any real, observable work done in the loop body of that thread, that loop body could not be reordered relative to `stopped==true` check.

Comment: The thing is that the thread is reading from a serial port that must be closed after using it, but moreover, the thread is running a member function of an object, and it changes some attributes of that object. The thing is that if the object is destroyed before the thread, the thread sometimes attempts to modify an attribute and exits with a segmentation fault. So it needs a flag to stop and the object must wait for the thread to be stopped before being destroyed.